Promise not returning the real response
I have a page that contains tabs. When I click on a specific tab the component related to it is created. It goes in the ngOnInit and when I leave the tab onDestroy is called.
In my ngOnInit function I have an ther function that is called for initializing some fields. At first, the actual request is the good one but when I leave and goes to the same tab my variable pageModelResponse is not returning the good result but the old one. The actual request received in my browser is different from the one I have in my variable. Since I am in a project that is shared among teams I wonder if it is really needed to update to RxJS 7 in order to use lastValueFrom.
ComponentBase.ts:
public async initializeDefaults(): Promise<void> {
            const pageModelResponse = await this.alertService.getPageModel(this.masterFeatureId).toPromise();
            this.pageModel = pageModelResponse?.data as AlertProfilePageModel;
            this.selectedSortOption = this.pageModel?.sortOptions?.find((x: SortOption) => x.isSelected) ?? {} as SortOption;
            this.getCurrentUrlParams();
}

Component.ts:
public async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
    await this.initializeDefaults();
}


According to this answer, ngOnit is not executed asynchronously. Its execution is not awaited.

Convert the sequence to an observable, unless you have a specific need for a promise, always opt for observables. But I think the problem is somewhere else in your code, please share a minimal reproducible example for checking.
ComponentBase.ts:
public initializeDefaults(): void {
     this.subscription.add(
       this.alertService.getPageModel(this.masterFeatureId).subscribe((pageModelResponse: any) => {
            this.pageModel = pageModelResponse?.data as AlertProfilePageModel;
            this.selectedSortOption = this.pageModel?.sortOptions?.find((x: SortOption) => x.isSelected) ?? {} as SortOption;
            this.getCurrentUrlParams();
      })
    );
}

Component.ts:
public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initializeDefaults();
}


Unfortunately I need to await the initialiaze function since some work depend on that ...

@guiz could you try this and see if the issue gets fixed?

I have tried but I have an exeption for undefined variable since a call is made with the this.selectedSortOption variable after that

@guiz we should move that logic inside the subscribe then!

I will try to refactor the whole code then
